# How to add a new Dijit widget to a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, dojo

I have a form with variable number of inputs. The behavior I am looking is to have a link in which user can click on and add a new input to the form that can be filled. something like this

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">  
  <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Textarea"/>  
  <a href="#" onclick="add_new_input()"> add a new input</a>  
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>  
  function add_new_input(){  
    var newInput = $("<input data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Textarea'/> ");  
    $('#myform').append(newInput);  
  }  
</script>
```

This will add a regular text input to the HTML and not a dijit widget!
Do you have any suggestions?

I also do this by defining a class for the input file and bind the input type on ($document).ready() but that did not work either! :(

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle (or similar) to post an example?

Comment: Sorry, it did not post correctly, I edited the post

Comment: I'm not sure adding in that way is sufficient. You probably need to either get dojo to parse that new content (in order to create the dijit reference), or create a dijit programmatically - i.e. `new Textarea({...}, "the_id_of_the_new_input")`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, how should I do it? I can generate a new ID for the tag. let's say it is save in the variable the_id_of_the_new_input. Is it enough to add:
new Textarea({}, the_id_of_the_new_input);
after appending the input in the JS code?

Comment: I made this one http://jsfiddle.net/humLq/3/

Comment: Thanks Robert, but what i can see is a normal textarea and not the dojo-type-textarea.

Comment: Now i updated the fiddle to this one http://jsfiddle.net/humLq/5/ ...the first area its dojo type...the other not...see the fiddle

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the issue that I have... do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I give up....it seams that dojo  parse its called onload event, so if you add dom elements they not receive the dojo atributes

Comment: If you are using dojo, you don't really need jQuery.  Dojo has query and byId methods already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pretty simple problem to solve by creating your Textarea widget programmatically (as mentioned by @Paul Grime). You can [see my example here](http://jsfiddle.net/humLq/8/) where all the textareas created by the link are Dijit widgets. I did not use jQuery in my fiddle, but all you need to do is change your `add_new_input` function to

```
function add_new_input (){
  var newInput = new Textarea({

    // Your custom properties here.

  });
  domConstruct.place(newInput.domNode, "myform");

  // Can alternatively place it as so if you don't want to use the
  // dojo/dom-construct module...
  // dojo.byId('myform').appendChild(newInput.domNode);   

  // Or with jQuery...
  // $("myform").append(newInput.domNode);
}
```